# object 'Spotify' has no attribute 'devices' - Spotipy doesn't have all attributes related to track control

Tags: python, python-3.x, spotipy

```
import sys
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util

username = "un"
scope = 'user-library-read'

token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username,scope)

if token:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
    devices=spotipy.client.Spotify.devices()
    print(devices)

else:
    print("Can't get token for", username)
```

This small script is supposed to print out the devices but I get the error `AttributeError: type object 'Spotify' has no attribute 'devices'`

I have checked version of spotipy. It is 2.4.4 now. Installation is complete but most of the playback functions of client object in this [documentation](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/spotipy/latest/spotipy.pdf) are missing and gives the same eror message. Why are they absent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I had the same problem after I installed SpotiPy through pip.
   I solved my problem by downloading the module trough [GitHub](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy), uninstalled the wrong module with `pip uninstall spotipy` and installed the downloaded module with `python setup.py install`.
2. According to [this page](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/get-a-users-available-devices/), the correct scope is `user-read-playback-state`.
3. Instead of using `devices=spotipy.client.Spotify.devices()`, you need to use `devices=sp.devices()`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think it was something about the installation. I probably forgot to change the scope, I didn't realize because it didn't throw an error. I apprecite that you pointed out other errors.

Comment: Sorry, I replied early. I have made all changes but am still getting the same error message.

Comment: Sorry to hear it didn't work. Maybe you need to uninstall the module first before installing the setup.py.

Comment: Yep that works. Thanks. I wonder when they will solve the issue.